# How can I create a BufferedImage from an SVG path?

Tags: java, svg

I have attempted to find this answer (on Google and Stackoverflow) without success, but I'm sure it must have been asked before, so feel free to point me onwards to the answer if it exists.

Currently, I have a Java servlet that loads a PNG from disk into a BufferedImage, writes text on top of it, and then streams back the byte[] to the client.

My desire is to replace the PNG-from-disk with a rendered SVG path, from a collection of icon-paths that I've source online (e.g. *"M21.871,9.814 15.684,16.001 21.871,22.188 18.335,25.725 8.612,16.001 18.335,6.276z"* and *"M22.727,18.242L4.792,27.208l8.966-8.966l-4.483-4.484l17.933-8.966l-8.966,8.966L22.727,18.242z"*).

I've come across [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) and [SVG Salamander](http://svgsalamander.java.net/), but am struggling to understand how I would accomplish the above with either of them, most specifically, how to render the SVG path into the BufferedImage. I need to be able to specify (a) the dimensions of the image, (b) the fill-color and (c) & (d) the stroke width and color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.mail-archive.com/batik-users@xml.apache.org/msg00775.html) is an example that basically uses the [Transcoder API](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html).

Comment: I've found lots of examples and discussion regarding loading SVG files, but I don't have SVG files. I have SVG paths, and I've not yet seen any way of parsing those pages into an object that can then be rendered into a BufferedImage. Am I missing something? Is there some easy way of converting the path into an SVG file?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "parsing those paths", not "parsing those pages"!!

Comment: Yes, it is string concatenation. `String svgFile = "<?xml ... ?><svg><path d=\"" + myPaths + "\" /></svg>"; new TranscoderInput( new java.io.StringReader( svgFile ) )`

Comment: Thank you: that works perfectly. If I get a chance (and once I know it's bug-free) I'll try to put my now-working code into my question.